Docker fist implementation: not showing Angular frontend
I am trying to set up Docket in this stack: Angular 18.2, Python 3.12.5, Django 5.1, Posgres 16.4.
I tried setting up a Dockerfile in each of the Backend and Frontend folders, also I created docker-compose.yaml and .dockerignore in the root folder.
After solving various problems it seems to be working, the problem is that I can't see the frontend DOM. The localhost is not reachable. But if I try to run the payers separately I am able to see. So I definitely made some mistakes along the way. I share the files and the folders tree.
Dockercompose
services:
      backend:
        build:
          context: ../BACKEND/humatic
          dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
          - ../BACKEND/humatic:/app/humatic
        environment:
          - DEBUG=True
          - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:humatic@db:5432/humatic
    
      frontend:
        build:
          context: ../FRONTEND/humatic
          dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "4200:80"
        volumes:
          - ../FRONTEND/humatic:/app/humatic
        environment:
          - API_URL=http://backend:8000/api
        command: /bin/bash -c "npm install && ng serve"
    
      db:
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: humatic
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: humatic

Dockerignore
    __pycache__
    *.pyc
    *.pyo
    *.pyd
    node_modules
    npm-debug.log

Dockerfile (backend)
    # Usa una versione compatibile di Python
    FROM python:3.11
    
    # Imposta la directory di lavoro
    WORKDIR /app/humatic
    
    # Copia il file dei requisiti
    COPY requirements.txt .
    
    # Installa le dipendenze, compreso Django
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
    
    # Copia il resto del codice
    COPY . .
    
    # Esegui il comando per avviare l'applicazione Django
    CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

Dockerfile (frontend)
# Usa una versione compatibile di Node.js per build
FROM node:18 AS build

# Imposta la directory di lavoro
WORKDIR /app/humatic

# Copia i file di configurazione
COPY package*.json ./

# Installa le dipendenze e Angular CLI
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli && \
    npm install

# Copia il resto del codice
COPY . .

# Compila l'applicazione
RUN npm run build --prod

# Usa nginx per servire l'app compilata
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copia il build dell'app nel percorso di default di nginx
COPY --from=build /app/humatic/dist/humatic /usr/share/nginx/html

# Espone la porta 80 per l'applicazione
EXPOSE 80

# Comando per avviare nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

This is the folders tree:

Thanks for the help! 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
That's how I start Docker.
PS C:\Progetti\humatic\docker> docker compose up
[+] Running 3/0
 ✔ Container docker-db-1        Created                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container docker-backend-1   Created                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container docker-frontend-1  Created                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
Attaching to backend-1, db-1, frontend-1
db-1        | 
db-1        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db-1        | 
db-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.612 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bitdb-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.612 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.612 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.628 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.643 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-29 20:18:21 UTC
db-1        | 2024-08-29 20:18:29.653 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend-1   | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
frontend-1  | 
frontend-1  | up to date, audited 982 packages in 4s
frontend-1  | 
frontend-1  | 147 packages are looking for funding
frontend-1  |   run `npm fund` for details
frontend-1  | 
frontend-1  | 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
frontend-1  | 
frontend-1  | Some issues need review, and may require choosing
frontend-1  | a different dependency.
frontend-1  | 
frontend-1  | Run `npm audit` for details.


v View in Docker Desktop   o View Config   w Enable Watch

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/oj1CbnA4.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ixy4GiNW.png

That's what I get from frontend.

The goal is to get two values to the db from backend and send them to frontend. It works if I run the layers separately.

You're trying to access http://127.0.0.1:4200 or http://localhost:4200 right?

Can you clarify further the exact problem you're running into?  What URL are you typing into the browser, and what result do you get?  There are a couple things possible in the setup you show – the application containers shouldn't have volumes: but the database should, the API_URL is wrong if the browser will be using it – but without knowing what specifically is going wrong it's a little hard to say more.

Yes, @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm trying to access to http://localhost:4200, as I do when I run frontend, backend and db seperately without docker, and it works, but with docker doesn't.

@DavidMaze I'm trying to get an API from backend which is http://localhost:8000/api/dummy-transactions/ which doesn't work when I start docker, and also I'm trying to visualize the fronted but I cant, the lo  localhost:4200 it's unreachable.
The goal is to show what I get from the API.

In those URLs, what is localhost?  (The system running the end user's browser; the backend container; something else?)  This sounds like it may be similar to the issue described in "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend, where the host names visible to browser-based applications are different from what's in containers.

The configuration in your compose file for the frontend seems weird given its Dockerfile. The Dockerfile seems to configure NGINX for serving your built up frontend on port 80, while the compose file seems to: 1) Use a volume with the frontend code, 2) Run ng serve to serve your frontend instead, 3) Map port 4200 to port 80 in the container even though now that you've replaced the command run by the image NGINX won't be running anymore.
